# How to make Dijkstra's Algorithm bidirectional

Tags: java, dijkstra

Currently, for any Edge (x,y) only the y Vertex is being added to my adjacency list. If I had another Edge (z,x), it only shows that y is a neighbor of x, when both y and z should be neighbors of x. I've tried using two hashmaps, one for the start Vertex, one for the end Vertex, then merging these two adjacency lists but this hasn't changed anything. That example is currently in my calculatesSource() method, one of the methods below. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
public class ReadInput {
    Vertex[] vertex = new Vertex[25252];
    final String DELIMITER = ",";
    int indexVertex = 0;
    public Edge[] edge = new Edge[127807];
    int indexEdge = 0; 

    private  Map<Integer, Vertex> VertexHash = new HashMap();
    //private  Map<Integer, List <Edge>> EdgeHash = new HashMap();
    private  Map<Integer, Edge> EdgeHashStart = new HashMap();
    private  Map<Integer, Edge> EdgeHashEnd = new HashMap();

    public Graph readFromStream() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
         Graph graph = new Graph();
         //25252 number of elements in Place.txt file   
         System.out.println("Reading in Data......");
        //Delimiter used in CSV file
            String line = "";
            //Create the file reader
            BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Place.txt"));
            String IDString = null;
            String name = null;
            int ID = 0;
            //Read the file line by line
            while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                //Get all tokens available in line
                String[] tokens = line.split(DELIMITER);

                     IDString = tokens[0];
                     name = tokens[1];
                     ID = Integer.parseInt(IDString);

                 vertex[indexVertex] = new Vertex(ID,name);
                 VertexHash.put(ID, vertex[indexVertex]);

                 graph.addVertex(ID,name);

                indexVertex++;
            }
            fileReader.close();


        String line2 = "";
        BufferedReader fileReader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Road.txt"));
        String valueString = null;
        String vertex1IDName = null;
        String vertex2IDName = null;
        String extra = null;
        float value = 0;
        int vertex1ID = 0;
        int vertex2ID = 0;
        //Read the file line by line
        while ((line2 = fileReader2.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            //Get all tokens available in line
            String[] tokens2 = line2.split(DELIMITER);

                vertex1IDName = tokens2[0];
                vertex2IDName = tokens2[1];
                valueString = tokens2[2];
                if(tokens2.length - 1 == 3) {
                    extra = tokens2[tokens2.length - 1];
                }
                else {
                    extra = "";
                }
                vertex1ID = Integer.parseInt(vertex1IDName);
                vertex2ID = Integer.parseInt(vertex2IDName);
                value = Float.parseFloat(valueString);





                Vertex v1 = new Vertex(0, " ");
                Vertex v2 = new Vertex(0, " ");

                if(VertexHash.containsKey(vertex1ID) ) {
                    v1 = VertexHash.get(vertex1ID);
                }
                else if(vertex1ID != 0 && (VertexHash.containsKey(vertex1ID) == false)) {
                    v1.setID(vertex1ID);
                }
                if(VertexHash.containsKey(vertex2ID)) {
                    v2 = VertexHash.get(vertex2ID);
                }
                else if(vertex2ID != 0 && (VertexHash.containsKey(vertex2ID) == false)) {
                    v2.setID(vertex2ID);
                }

                if(v1.getID() != 0 && v2.getID() !=0) {

                    edge[indexEdge] = new Edge(value,v1, v2, extra);
                    EdgeHashStart.put(v1.getID(),edge[indexEdge]);
                    EdgeHashEnd.put(v2.getID(),edge[indexEdge]);

                    v1.addNeighbour(edge[indexEdge]);
                    //adding v2 as a neighbor just adds the actualVertex being worked on "x" to the adj list
                    //v2.addNeighbour(edge[indexEdge]);
                    graph.addEdge(value,v1, v2, extra);
                    indexEdge++;
                }   
        } 
        fileReader2.close();
        return graph;

    }
    public Vertex calcualteDestination() {

        Scanner scanUserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Destination Name:");
        String destinationName = scanUserInput.nextLine();
        scanUserInput.close();

         Vertex Destination = new Vertex(0,null);

       for(int i = 0; i<indexVertex; i++) {
           if(destinationName.equals(vertex[i].getName())){

               Destination.setID(vertex[i].getID());
               Destination.setName(vertex[i].getName());

           }
       }   
        for(int k = 0; k<indexEdge; k++) {
            if(Destination.getID() == edge[k].getTargetVertex().getID()){
                Destination.setID(edge[k].getTargetVertex().getID());
                Destination.setAdjacenciesList(edge[k].getTargetVertex().getAdjacenciesList());

            }
       } 
        return Destination;
    }

    public Vertex calculatesSource() {
        Scanner scanUserInput = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter the Source Name:");
        String sourceName = scanUserInput.nextLine();

        Vertex Source = new Vertex(0, null);

        for(int i = 0; i<indexVertex; i++) {
            if(sourceName.equals(vertex[i].getName())){

                Source.setID(vertex[i].getID());

                Source.setName(vertex[i].getName());

            }
        }   

            //for(int k = 0; k<indexEdge; k++) {
                //(sourceID,getAdjList) 
                //need to add (GetADjList,sourceID)
                List<Edge> listMerge = new ArrayList<Edge>(); 
                if(EdgeHashStart.containsKey(Source.getID())) {
                    //add all to adj list
                    listMerge.addAll(EdgeHashStart.get(Source.getID()).getStartVertex().getAdjacenciesList());
                }
                if(EdgeHashEnd.containsKey(Source.getID())) {
                    //add all to adj list
                    listMerge.addAll(EdgeHashEnd.get(Source.getID()).getTargetVertex().getAdjacenciesList());
                }
                Source.setAdjacenciesList(listMerge);
                //old setADjLists code
                /*if(Source.getID() == edge[k].getStartVertex().getID()){
                    Source.setID(edge[k].getStartVertex().getID());
                    Source.setAdjacenciesList(edge[k].getStartVertex().getAdjacenciesList());

                }*/
             //}
        return Source;
    }


    public Vertex SetAdjList(Vertex actualVertex) {

        for(int j = 0; j<edge.length-1; j++) {

            if(actualVertex.getID() == edge[j].getTargetVertex().getID()){  //edge[j].getStartVertex

                actualVertex.setAdjacenciesList(edge[j].getTargetVertex().getAdjacenciesList());
            }
        }

        return actualVertex;
    }
```

Comment: Please post [mre]. Hard code test data instead of reading from a file which is not available to us.